# dynamic scraping in nativescript? need to scrape page, with ability to click html button

Tags: javascript, cordova, dynamic, screen-scraping, nativescript

do any package exist/ or process exist in native-script, for scraping dynamic content, means ability to click HTML button? 
or 
do i need to switch to cordova, for this ability?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking for. Please rephrase the questions. If you're asking about web scraping it could easily be solved by using the NativeScript HTTP module ( http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/http/HOW-TO ) and a parsing library such as Cheerio ( http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/ )

Comment: Why would you want to scrape dynamic content using an app?

Comment: @EmilOberg http does not have ability to click html button, and cheerio is not supported, what i found out.

Comment: @MikeResoli page what i want to scrap have 2 dropdown box, which have to be selected(user may select any), after this event , button need to be clicked, i tried FireBug, but can't find the URL

Comment: now i think it will be better to use Web Service Approach

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question (and subsequent comments) you want to (in a NativeScript app):

1. Load a website
2. Select a value in two select boxes
3. Press the submit button

The big question here is what happens when you press the submit button. Most probably this will result in a POST/PATCH being sent to a server.

The way of solving this would be:

1. Use the [HTTP Module](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/http/HOW-TO) of NativeScript to download the web page.
2. Use [Cheerio](http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/) (or just plain regular expressions) to get the data needed to render the two select boxes and the URI to where to post the form.
3. Based on the data from (2) create and populate the two select boxes in NativeScript and save the POST uri somewhere.
4. Create an "on-submit" function which, based on the select boxes, creates the payload in the format the server wants it and then use HTTP Module again to post it to the URI.

To see the network traffic going on between the client (your browser) and the server, just open up the Networks Panel of your web browser, e.g. [for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

Looking at the network data should get tell you where to POST the data and how the payload should look like.

This can, of course, also be seen by looking at the code of the webpage.

Comment: is Cheerio supported in nativescript??

Comment: let me try and will inform you soon

Comment: Also, check out this plugin mentioned on the {N} blog: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/plugin-nativescript-webview-interface  this would allow you to get the info from the webview in your NativeScript app.

Comment: Better to use API in middle, for scraping